# find previous sunday date based on today date in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Let us consider today date as 09/11/2021

And previous sunday date is 31/10/2021

today = datetime.date.today()

Now find previous sunday date

Comment: Why is previous Sunday not 07/11/2021? What is the rule?

Comment: 7/11/2021 is this week sunday but i need previous week

Comment: If today was a Sunday would you return one week ago or two?

Answer (score 0):

You can use relativedelta from dateutil.

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta, SU
last_sunday = date.today() + relativedelta(weekday=SU(-2))
```

Comment: in this way i am getting 7/11/2021 not 31/10/2020 which is previous week sunday

Comment: then use -2 instead if thats want you want, the number is how many sundays you want to go back, starting from 0 which is the next upcoming sunday.

Answer (score 0):

```
last_sunday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday() + 8)
```